# "Writing a business letter" vs "Writing business letters"

Tags: grammar, articles, zero-article

Am I right that we need indefinite article in this sentence:

> Writing a business letter.

but we don't need any article in this sentence:

> Writing business letters.

(it could be a  title for a post in a blog, for example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct. Plural nouns use a definite article (ie. Writing the business letters) or no article at all, just as you did.

Here is a link that explains it: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/articles-with-plural-nouns/